# Convert regex to htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I have the following html element:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <span class="wrapper2">
          <div class="myClass">
           MyString   
           </div>
           <button>buttonText</button>
     </span>
</div>   

So, I need to convert that element to be
```

`≤MyString≥ free text <br> <i> <u>..... ≤MyString≥`

So, I figured out how to do conversion from html to my special characters, but cannot figure out how to do conversion backwards to html in htmlAgilityPack and XPath. I was able to do it purely in regex, but it's not the best solution.

From html to specialchars:

```
   private  string transformFromHtmlToMergeCodes(string text)
            {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(text);
                var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='wrapper']");
                foreach (var item in nodes)
                {
                    var innerText = "≤" + item.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myClass']").InnerText + "≥";
                    var textNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(innerText);
                    item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(textNode,item);
                }
                return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

            }
```

From special chars to html:

```
 private  string transformFromMergeCodesToHtml(string text)
        {
            var matches  = Regex.Matches(text, @"\«(.*?)\»");
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var innerText = match.Value
                                     .Replace("≤", @"<div class=""wrapper"" contenteditable=""false"">
                                                    <span class=""wrapper2"">
                                                    <div class=""myClass"">").Replace("≥",@"</div><button type="" button"" class=""MergeCodeRemoveIcon"">×</button></span></div>");
                text = text.Replace(match.Value, innerText);
            }
            return text;
        }
```

So, it's the second function I want to modify to use htmlAgilityPack because this is not the most efficient approach, especially if I have duplicated nodes.
I was trying to find `≤MyString≥` and convert it to node, but HtmlAgilityPack throws an error, that it's not a valid node (Which makes sense.) Any suggestions?
**Edit**
To be clear. Here's the conversion I want to perform:
Before:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <span class="wrapper2">
          <div class="myClass">
           MyString   
           </div>
           <button>buttonText</button>
     </span>
</div>  
free text <br> <i> <u>.....   
<div class="wrapper">
     <span class="wrapper2">
          <div class="myClass">
           MyString2   
           </div>
           <button>buttonText</button>
     </span>
</div>
```

After:

```
`≤MyString≥ free text <br> <i> <u>..... ≤MyString2≥`
```

**And Vice Versa**

Comment: Can you add the before and after HTML for each step, so that I better understand what you're after...

Comment: +1 for looking for an HtmlAgilityPack answer by the way!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, this might do the trick. If not, please show clear before, in between, after of what the intended text should look like.

```
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("#text").Where(text => Regex.IsMatch(text.InnerText.Trim(), @"≤[^≥]*≥"));
        string format =
            @"<div class=""wrapper"" contenteditable=""false""><span class=""wrapper2""><div class=""myClass"">{0}</div><button type="" button"" class=""MergeCodeRemoveIcon"">×</button></span></div>";

        foreach (var htmlNode in nodes)
        {
            htmlNode.InnerHtml = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, htmlNode.InnerText.Trim().Trim(new[] { '≤', '≥' }));
        }

        return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

---

Try this:

```
    private static string transformFromMergeCodesToHtml(string textWithMergeCodes)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(textWithMergeCodes);

        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("#text").Where(text => Regex.IsMatch(text.InnerText.Trim(), @"≤[^≥]*≥"));
        string format =
            @"<div class=""wrapper"" contenteditable=""false""><span class=""wrapper2""><div class=""myClass"">$2</div><button type="" button"" class=""MergeCodeRemoveIcon"">×</button></span></div>";

        foreach (var htmlNode in nodes)
        {
            htmlNode.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(htmlNode.InnerText.Trim(), @"(≤)([^≥]*)(≥)", format);
        }
        return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }

    private static string transformFromHtmlToMergeCodes(string text)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(text);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='wrapper']");
        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            var innerText = "≤" + item.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myClass']").InnerText.Trim() + "≥";
            var textNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(innerText);
            item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(textNode, item);
        }
        return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

    }
```

NOTE: I updated the other method as well!

Comment: Let me try your approach though really quick

Comment: Ok, I've just tested it, doesn't complete work as expected (I believe something wrong with regex.)

Comment: I see where it's going wrong... The text is no longer in a tag per se... No longer behind pc will look at this in my morning..